# How can I count and display the count for petition questions/activities

Tags: activities, civicampaign

I have a petition. It has 3 questions which have 3 possible answers each.
eg Will you back my campaign to do X? answers: yes/no/not sure

I would like to be able to quickly display the results of my survey as I can in webform.

What should I use to do this. I can count one question with one answer using views but can't see how I would use views to count all the answers to each question and display them.

I can't work out how to count the activities in reports. I am only looking to display the questions and answers in text form (not graphically)

Any thoughts!?

PS if anyone knows how to find the activities in the SQL table that might help also